# owl-carousel is showing items vertically before finishing loading

Tags: owl-carousel-2

My owl-carousel is showing items vertically before finishing loading.
after finishing loading the slider work properly,How can I fix that? 
*I'm using owl-carousel 2
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved .. 
the problem was that i added "owl-loaded" class to my slider's container .. i removed it and it worked ..